# copying data from table to table sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

can I copy data from table to another using this query:

```
// table1( tid , uid, name, link)

// table2(mid , uid  , name, link) 

query = "INERT INTO TABLE2 ("+ getIdFromFunction()+" , uid, name, link) SELECT * FROM TABLE1";
```

I want to fill table2 from table1, but will be with certain value each time I call this query

its like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (0, uid, name, link) SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

is that possible ??

Comment: You cannot combine it, first retrieve values and then create your insert statement with values retrieved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `INSERT` command has a list of column names; the values are specified in the `SELECT` command.
So you want this:

```
INSERT INTO table2(mid, uid, name, link)
SELECT 0, uid, name link
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

@MBH No you can't use select* from Table1 in the insert statement..First you have to assign the records from table1 into record and then only you can pass the values into table2..your code should like below

```
declare
 r record;
select into r tid , uid, name, link from tale1;
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (tid, uid, name, link) values 
     (INSERT INTO TABLE2 (r.tid r.uid,r.name, r.link))
```